# Wordpress get_posts returns correct results but won't load subsequent functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm querying two taxonomies with this code:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 1,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'include'         => '',
    'exclude'         => '',
    'meta_key'        => '',
    'meta_value'      => '',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'  => '',
    'post_parent'     => '',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms' => '16',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        ),
        array(
        'taxonomy' => $this_taxonomy,
        'terms' => $this_page,
        'field' => 'slug',
        )
    )
);
$myposts2 = get_posts( $args );
```

And it returns a good result (the resulting post object has the right category and taxonomy/slug assignments).

But when I try to use subsequent functions like this:

```
<?php foreach ( $myposts2 as $post2 ) : ?>
    <li class="product-details">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink($post2->ID); ?>"><?php get_the_post_thumbnail( $post2->ID, 'medium' ); ?><h3><?php $post2->post_title; ?></h3></a>
</li>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I end up with the wrong results for the permalink and no results for title or thumbnail.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, BA_Webimax! There were some additional things wrong with the code, but the reference link you sent helped me in the right direction. I wasn't expecting WP to require me to call the object $post (instead of $post2). Also, I was using the wrong functions to retrieve the bits. get_permalink() was fine, but I should have been using the_post_thumbnail() and the_title() instead of the functions I'd chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw in a `setup_postdata()` call in there. See here for details... https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata

```
<?php foreach ( $myposts2 as $post2 ) :
    setup_postdata($post2); ?>
    <li class="product-details">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink($post2->ID); ?>"><?php get_the_post_thumbnail( $post2->ID, 'medium' ); ?><h3><?php $post2->post_title; ?></h3></a>
</li>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```